Add a Returns and Refunds policy checkbox with a link below WooCommerce terms and conditions checkbox
I want to add a Returns and Refunds Policy checkbox below the Terms and Conditions checkbox on WooCommerce. I have created the Returns and Refunds page and I'd like a similar function as Terms and Conditions wherein a box will appear below upon clicking the link.
I've tried adding this code in code snippets:
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'bbloomer_add_checkout_privacy_policy', 9 );
    
function bbloomer_add_checkout_privacy_policy() {
   
woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy', array(
   'type'          => 'checkbox',
   'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
   'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
   'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
   'required'      => true,
   'label'         => 'I have read and agree to the Returns and Refunds policy',
)); 
   
}


The checkbox was formed below the terms and conditions but I don't know how to create the link to Returns and Refunds. Any advice on how I can resolve this? Thank you.

To add a link to a custom "Returns and Refunds Policy" checkbox below the Terms and Conditions checkbox on WooCommerce and add the required validation use the following instead (where you will define your "Returns and Refunds Policy" page link Url):
// Add a custom checkbox to checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_custom_checkout_privacy_policy', 9 ); 
function add_custom_checkout_privacy_policy() {
    // Here define the privacy policy link page URL
    $page_link = site_url('/privacy-policy/');

    $privacy_text = sprintf( __("I have read and agree to the website %s", 'woocommerce'), 
        '<a href="'. $page_link .'">'. __("returns and refunds policy", 'woocommerce') . '</a>');
   
    printf('<p class="form-row privacy validate-required privacy_policy_field">
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" %s />
        <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text">%s</span>
        &nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="%s">*</abbr>
    </label></p>', checked( isset($_POST['privacy_policy']), true, false ), 
    $privacy_text, esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' ) );
}

// Checkbox validation as it's a required field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_custom_checkout_privacy_policy' ); 
function validate_custom_checkout_privacy_policy() {
    if ( ! isset($_POST['privacy_policy']) ) {
        wc_add_notice('Please read and accept the returns and refunds policy to proceed with your order.', 'error');
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.



